# E11000 duplicate key error collection: amaxon.products index: name_1 dup key: { name: "Nike SLim Shirt" }

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

The following is `productShema` model in my `productModel.js`:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    image: { type: String, required: true },
    brand: { type: String, required: true },
    category: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    countInStock: { type: Number, required: true },
    rating: { type: Number, required: true },
    numReviews: { type: Number, required: true },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
)
const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema)

export default Product
```

and this is how I am using this in `productRouter.js`:

```
import express from 'express'
import Product from '../models/productModel.js'
import expressAsyncHandler from 'express-async-handler'
import data from '../data.js'

const productRouter = express.Router()

productRouter.get(
  '/',
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const products = await Product.find({})
    res.send(products)
  })
)

productRouter.get(
  '/seed',
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    // await Product.remove({});
    const createdProducts = await Product.insertMany(data.products)
    res.send({ createdProducts })
  })
)

productRouter.get(
  '/:id',
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id)
    if (product) {
      res.send(product)
    } else {
      res.status(404).send({ message: 'Product not found' })
    }
  })
)

export default productRouter
```

In `data.products` I have 6 products and then I try get the data from `http://localhost:5000/api/products/seed` this address and it shows me this:

> "E11000 duplicate key error collection: amaxon.products index: name_1 dup key: { name: "Nike SLim Shirt" }"

and when I Try to get the data from `http://localhost:5000/api/products` it gives me only one product. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert the data instead use `find`. Check this:

```
productRouter.get(
  '/seed',
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    // await Product.remove({});
    const createdProducts = await Product.find({})
    res.send({ createdProducts })
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `name` property is set to be a **unique**, make sure to:

1. remove all the data stored in the `Product mongo collection` before calling the `seed` endpoint again. *(you have it commented out - `await Product.remove({});`)*
2. all the names in the `data.js` are unique.